# How to edit the NewProducts block magento

Tags: products

I have a new question. I am trying to remove TAX information from the New Products block from home page but not successful. Can somebody help me with this problem? I dont fine witch file I need to edit to remove this information from this block and Sale Products blcok. Any suggestions are welcomed. Thank you[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use template path hints.

```
System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Debug -> template path hints ->yes.
```

Don't forget to change the scope to main website..

Refresh  the website..

It will display the path..

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer but in my admin is no so function Debug -> template path hints ->yes

Comment: Hi...Change the current configuration scope to Main website(top left drop-down menu)

Comment: ok, now I found the file. but I dont know what to change on it. maybe you can help me with this little problem? the file is frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml
or the site address is www.modernmobel.de

Answer (score 1):

In your admin panel, look in `System->Configuration->Sales->Tax->Display Product Prices In Catalog`.  Does that setting say "Including Tax"? If so, turn that setting off and it will no longer display tax in your cart.